# How can I change the order of citations in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2010

When I insert citations into my document, they are automatically ordered by their first appearance in the document. However, instead I want them to be ordered how I like, such as:

1. Books
2. Articles
3. Web pages

How can I specify such an ordering?